# Getting NSDateComponents' value for an NSCalendarUnit in a variable

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsdatecomponents

To get the minute value from an `NSDateComponents` object, you do this:

```
var someNSDateComponentsObject: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(timeUnit, fromDate: someDate, toDate: someOtherDate, options: nil)
someNSDateComponentsObject.minute
```

What if instead of doing `someNSDateComponentsObject.minute`, I wanted to use the value of `timeUnit`, which is an `NSCalendarUnit`? Would a switch statement be the only option, or is there a more elegant solution?

Overall, the thing I'm trying to accomplish is to get the number of `timeUnit`s between two dates. Is there a better way to do so that would avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In iOS 8 `NSDateComponents` gained](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/Foundation.html) the how-did-this-not-exist-before method `valueForComponent:` (and its partner `setValue:forComponent:`), which strangely hasn't made its way into the class reference doc yet. It does what you'd expect: given an `NSCalendarUnit`, it returns the value the date components instance holds for that unit.